i have failed in flutter_osm
I am do a function to add a marker in the map and print alongside and latitude
  getMyLocationOsm() async {
 final map_controller = MapController(initMapWithUserPosition: true);
    try {
      GeoPoint geoPoint = await map_controller.myLocation();
      double lat = geoPoint.latitude;
      double long = geoPoint.longitude;
      print("latitude is :$lat,  longitude is:$long");
       map_controller.addMarker(
            geoPoint,
            markerIcon:const MarkerIcon(
                icon: Icon(
              Icons.location_history_rounded,
              color: Colors.red,
              size: 48,
            )
            ),
          );
    } on GeoPointException catch (e) {
      print("${e.errorMessage()}");
    }
  }

i am try many time without solved problem
